# ALSA PCM Non-Blocking Capture Producing Static

Tags: linux, alsa, pcm

Whenever I construct a non-blocking PCM capture stream in ALSA, I sometimes get garbage samples back when I call snd_pcm_readi() (meaning data gets populated, and I'm told I've just read N samples, but only M are valid, the rest is just garbage). This tells me that the samples aren't actually ready, so I don't understand why ALSA would even return them.

For those who have the ALSA-provided `latency` tool lying around someplace, I can reproduce this static by running `latency -P <playback-device> -C <capture-device> -r 48000`. ALSA begins normalizing around a roundtrip time of 16ms for me, but it just *sounds* atrocious.

I was able to capture some of the bad data, and I loaded it up in Audacity for visualization:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-1aumGKQcQTcUJoZzIwRWhYSFE/view?usp=sharing

It looks like the internal buffer occasionally is sending me more data than it actually captured, and I end up either reading old PCM data from the internal ring buffer, or (at the very beginning) a bunch of zeros.

Can anyone help me understand what is going on?

In case it helps:

- Hardware: Samson Meteor Mic (USB-Audio, USB Mixer) [Though, it even happens with my built-in microphone]
- ALSA version: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k4.4.0-28-generic.
- apt-cache policy (installed alsa-lib version): 1.1.0-0ubuntu1

EDIT:
I got a vote to close as off-topic, which I disagree with... I feel the API is not acting in accordance with what the documentation says, and don't understand *why*. I've rephrased the question to perhaps make it a little more clear, but if it still appears to be off-topic, please let me know why so I can either correct it or close it myself.